# CVE-2015-7547: glibc getaddrinfo stack-based buffer overflow

Tags: router

https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html

If I have an OpenWRT with default install, do I need to update, if we only count the threat from WAN/Internet side?

Comment: https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-tale-of-a-dns-exploit-cve-2015-7547/

Answer (score 3):

If it really is "default", then no update is required: OpenWRT has always used *uClibc* for its libc by default, it will not be vulnerable if so.

However, OpenWRT also supports *glibc* (and *musl*, which will be the default in the next release), so *it is possible to have a vulnerable OpenWRT*. Given the size and complexity of glibc, it's most likely that memory/storage constrained devices will not run a glibc version.

If you have a shell on the system, this should be useful:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120380/what-c-library-version-does-my-system-use

If you built/configured it yourself, check `CONFIG_LIBC` in the `.config` in your build directory. Otherwise, check with the provider of the OpenWRT installation.

(It is also possible, though *very* unlikely, to have multiple libc instances. The OpenWRT build system does not support this though.)